# bibliography not numbered

Tags: bibtex

I am unable to number my bibliography using bibtex and a chicago style downloaded for this purpose.  The numbering issue was present prior to the implementation of the chicago style add-in so I doubt that's the problem.  I have looked at other examples, many of which appear to be one option taking precedent over another or a separate package making the modification.  I can't seem to be able to figure this one out.  please help.  (Also, the brackets were not defaulting to round and I had to force the option, maybe that's a clue?)

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}   % improved mathematical formulas
\usepackage[round]{natbib}    % for citations (Endnote)
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\plim}{plim}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1cm} \addtolength{\hoffset}{-1cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2.5cm} \addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\section{}
etc...
\section{}
text

\clearpage

\bibliography{terrvar}  % terrvar.bib is the library

% followed by tables and figures
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the objective "numbering the bibliography section". In the posted answer, I've assumed you wish to get a numbered sectioning header. If this assumption is incorrect, and if you want numeric citation callouts instead, you should load `natbib` with the option `numbers`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `article` document class, you can get a numbered references section by adding the following instructions to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*}{\section}{}{}
```

If you were using the `report` or `book` document class (or a document class that's based on either of these classes) you'd replace `\section*` with `\chapter*` and `\section` with `\chapter`.